# JMeter sample response displaying in red with a warning in the View Results Tree table, error is: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm seeking assistance as I am new to JMeter. While creating my inaugural test case, I encountered a warning in the View Results Table highlighted in red, specifically pointing to the issue

***identified as Thread Name:Thread1 1-1
Sample Start:2024-01-15 09:58:34 PKT
Load time:1070
Connect Time:1070
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2624
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2624
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to [www.w3schools.com:80](http://www.w3schools.com:80) [www.w3schools.com/192.229.133.221] failed: Connection refused: connect
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: null***

Despite having a stable network connection, I attempted to execute the test on different machines. Additionally, I have set the Java path and explored various approaches to address the error, but unfortunately, I have been unable to resolve it. Any guidance or insights to help overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a warning, it's an error and it means that JMeter cannot establish connection to server `www.w3schools.com` at port `80`

The website is normally available and I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image]

So my expectation is that either there is a problem with your network (i.e. the website is blocked by your ISP) or you're behind a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). In the latter case you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) by

- either setting the proxy details under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

  [image]
- or specifying its detail via [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- or setting them via [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: THANKS @Dmitri T, It worked after adding http request--> server name and port number.

Comment: I was accessing the Jmeter in official environment where firewall and proxies are implemented.  Now I entered as per your suggestions and got successfull results. Warning message disppeared and status of view result is successful. @Dmitri T